# Why is this pattern not matching the data my program reads from STDIN?

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose there is a list that is input from the console using `<STDIN>`

```
@string = <STDIN>;
```

Now, I check for a pattern, say `/manu/`, in my program

```
foreach (@string)
{
    if(/manu/)
    {
        print $_."\n";
    }
}
```

The code is unable to look for the pattern  `/manu/`.

However when I do the following, the code works perfectly fine:

```
chomp(@string = <STDIN>);
```

Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit:** My original answer was written assuming the code posted was the code the OP had used. Updated after the correction.

Here is what I get when run:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @string = <STDIN>;

for (@string) {
    if(/manu/) {
        print "'$_'";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
E:\> t
manu
nana
tada
^Z
'manu
'
```

Note the <kbd>Control-Z</kbd> which I use to signal EOF from the command line on Windows (if you are using a *nix shell, you would use <kbd>Control-D</kbd>).

Output only appears once your program reads all the data it can read from `STDIN`.

Note the newline printed after `manu`. That's because I did not `chomp` the input. That is the only difference between using this code versus using

```
chomp(my @string = <STDIN>)
```

When you first assign `<STDIN>` to an array and iterate over that, your program will wait until there is no more data to be read *and* its memory use will be proportional to the amount of data received.

On the other hand, the following program will process lines as they come:

```
/manu/ and print while <>;
```

and its memory use will be proportional to the longest line received.

The line above is equivalent to:

```
while ( <> ) {
    if ( /manu/ ) {
        print $_;
    }
}
```

Note that, you should always add `use strict;` and its close friend `use warnings;` to your scripts. See [perldoc strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html).

Answer (score 3):

In your first example, `@list` is undefined. If you would have had

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

in your script (highly recommended!), Perl would have told you about this.

Edit: Now that you've fixed this, the code you have works for me.

Answer (score -1):

chomp tears off any whitespace or cr/lfs. Add a chomp, or add any whitespace to your regex match, eg:

```
foreach (@string)
{
    if(/manu\s*/)
    {
        print $_."\n";
    }
}
```